Using Sculpt Mode for Shape Keys - Modeling
Can one make shape keys using multires modifier and sculpting?
I set the value to 1 on shape key, start sculpting and nothing moves when I slide the value of the shake key. Is it incompatible?

Never mind, I had to check on the modifier (sculpt base mesh), but it enables itself only when you go into sculpt mode. That way the shape keys work.
